# Photoshop: Saving pngs on randomizing function not working

Tags: javascript, png, photoshop, photoshop-script, psd

I'm trying to run a script on PS 2021 version to randomize the creation of PNG artworks. I've set up four groups with different layers on it. It randomizes the visibility of layers in a certain way. However, when it comes to saving the image as PNG it prompts the file explorer to save the file in PSD format.

This is the code I'm using right now:

```
function Visible() {
    var Grps = app.activeDocument.layerSets;

    //alert("total groups: "+ Grps.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < Grps.length; i++) {
        // Get the amount of layers in a set
        var tmp = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers.length;

        // set the whole group visible
        app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].visible = true;

        var groupChildArr = app.activeDocument.layerSets[i].layers;

        var randLays = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmp);

        groupChildArr[randLays].visible = true;

        Save();

    }
    Revert();
}
function Save() {
    var outFolder = app.activeDocument;

    var outPath = outFolder.path;

    var fName = "PNG";

    var f = new Folder(outPath + "/" + fName);
    if (!f.exists) {
        f.create()
    }
    //alert("before path config");
    var saveFile = new File(outPath + "/" + fName + "/" + "TREE_" + num + ".png");
    pngSaveOptions = new PNGSaveOptions();
    pngSaveOptions.interlaced = false;

    //alert("before save")
    app.activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, pngSaveOptions, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);
    //alert("after save")
}
function Revert() { 
    var idRvrt = charIDToTypeID("Rvrt"); 
    executeAction(idRvrt, undefined, DialogModes.NO); 
}
var count = prompt("How many versions you want", ""); 
for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) { 
    var num = x + 1; 
    Visible(); 
}
```

This is how it works, it asks for the number of pieces to generate:

[image]

And then it just prompts the explorer on each iteration:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to suppress any Photoshop dialog boxes that may pop up.
At the very start of your script put this:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF
```

You will also have to flatten the document as well. Add it just before the save:

```
    activeDocument.flatten();

    Save();
```

- Don't worry the revert function puts it back to how it was.

Comment: Thanks! Now the dialogs have ended but it's not saving anything yet :(

Comment: You need to flatten the document before saving - I've updated my answer.

Comment: I appreciate every help you're bringing me, still am not being able to achieve what i want. May i ask you if you can run the script with the layers of my project? It would be life saving

Comment: I've rerun everything commenting the Save() line and it does what it has to do, it's just the saveAs function that's not working